# T-SQL: Selecting the max year and then the max sequence using a CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select the max image entry in a table based on the year and then the sequence number so that I can update a 2nd table with the correct image file name.  In the example below sequence #, 2005765, is the correct image file.

[image: Image Table]

I have attempted to do this with:

```
WITH CTE (Year, ImageId, ImageSeq) AS   
(
    SELECT
        MAX(Year),
        Image_ID,
        Image_Seq
    FROM 
        PIMAGE
    WHERE 
        Type = 'PHOTO'
    GROUP BY 
        Image_ID, Image_Seq
)
SELECT
    cp.RPID,
    MAX(i.Sequence),
    i.File_Name
FROM
    CommProperty cp
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    CTE ON CTE.ImageId = cp.RPID
INNER JOIN 
    PIMAGE i ON i.Image_ID = cte.ImageId 
             AND i.Year = cte.Year 
             AND i.Image_Seq = cte.ImageSeq
WHERE 
    cp.RPID = 16107
GROUP BY 
    cp.RPID, i.File_Name
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) may help you improve your question.

Comment: "...select the max image entry..." What do you mean by max?

Comment: "...2005765, is the correct image file..." - Why?

Comment: @TheImpaler it is the image with the max year and the max sequence number.  And by max I mean it is the newest image based on the year, even though it doesn't have the highest sequence #.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY image_id ORDER BY year DESC, image_seq DESC) as seqnum
      FROM PIMAGE p
      WHERE p.Type = 'PHOTO'
     ) p
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```